# Golang: Using ElasticSearch library called Goes, how can I write executable code for bool should method?

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I'm using goes library (https://github.com/OwnLocal/goes), which is the wrapper for ElasticSearch in Golang.

In ElasticSearch queries, we can run like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "user_id_1": "438018"
    }
  }
}
```

and it works.

For golang using goes, you can run it like as:

```
var query = map[string]interface{}{
        "query": map[string]interface{}{
            "match": map[string]interface{}{
                "user_id_1": "438018",
            },
        },
    }
```

Here is my question, you can use this query in elasticsearch

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "year": "2016"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "frequency": "7"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the above code, it is the bool should clause written in documentation here (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_executing_searches.html)
So, I made query2 to search same way as elastic one.

```
var query2 = map[string]interface{}{
        "query": map[string]interface{}{
            "bool": map[string]interface{}{
                "should": map[string]interface{}{
                    "match": map[string]interface{}{
                        "year": "2016",
                    },
                    "match": map[string]interface{}{
                        "frequency": "7",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

**Error: duplicate key "match" in map literal**

I am not so familiar with interface on golang.
I hope some has a idea for that. Thanks.

p.s.

Thanks Tranvu Xuannhat :) it helped a lot !

```
var query2 = map[string]interface{}{
        "query": map[string]interface{}{
            "bool": map[string]interface{}{
                "should": []map[string]interface{}{
                    map[string]interface{}{
                        "match": map[string]interface{}{
                              "year": "2016",
                          },
                    },
                    map[string]interface{}{
                        "match": map[string]interface{}{
                              "frequency": "7",
                          },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

This is what I did finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done ElasticSearch with Golang before, but I see some mismatch between your original query and Go query. It should be array of map, each map has a key "match". Not a map with duplicate "match" (as the error)
I think in your Golang query, it should be:

```
   "should":[]map[string]interface{} {
        {       
                "match": map[string]interface{}{
                    "year": "2016",
               },
        },
        {
                "match": map[string]interface{}{
                    "frequency": "7",
                },
        },
   },
```